# Trying to understand how forms work and why document.location.href wont function

Tags: javascript, html, forms

scripts.js

```
function homepageInput() {
    var x = document.getElementById('homeForm').elements["whatdoyouwant"].value;
    if(x.localeCompare("working") == 0){
        document.location.href = 'new.html';
    }
}
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class= "boxContainer">
        <div id = "box">
            <form id="homeForm" onsubmit="homepageInput()">
                <input type="password" name="whatdoyouwant" id="whatdoyouwant" placeholder="WTF..."/>
                <input id="submit" type="submit"/>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

when i type "working" into my password field it wont load the page new.html which is located in the same directory. Any ideas? When i use an alert in the same if statement it loads fine?

Answer (score 0):

You trigger the function when you submit the form.

You do nothing to prevent the default behaviour of the form.

Consequently, you set `location.href` and then the form submission runs and you submit the form to the current URL.

---

The quick hack to solving this is to `return false` from your onsubmit function.

Modern code would bind the event handler [with JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) and use [`preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault).

Comment: thanks :) new to this, i put return false at the end of my function did nothing :/ . What is this default form behavior or where can i read up on it. I swear W3 school is cancer

Comment: The default form behaviour is "Take all the user input in the form, put it into a string, load a new page based on sending that information to the URL specified in the action (or the current URL if none is specified).

Comment: Are you sure you are returning false from the end of your onsubmit function? And not from your homepageInput function?

Comment: oh didnt think html onsubmit was classified as a function :/ haha so silly, first time playing with html, css javascript after codecademy. thanks for the help is working now :3